# How do I return a queryset of all items (X) ManyToMany related to model class (Y) and include values for (Y) in the same result in each item X

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have the following two model classes:

```
class Property(models.Model):
    """Represents property class model"""
    serial_no = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    map_no = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    lr_no =  models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    locality =  models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
```

```
class PropertyObjection(models.Model):
    """Represents property objection class. This has properties that have been objected"""
    objector_name = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
    objection_no = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
    properties =  models.ManyToManyField(Property,blank=True)
    ratable_owner = models.BooleanField(null=True,blank=True)
    ratable_relation = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
```

Which is the most effective way to get all properties that have been objected using the `PropertyObjection` class. One other thing to note is that each property should have values for `objection_no`, `ratable_owner` and `ratable_relation` values.

The expected result should look something like this:

```
[
    {
    'objector_name': "Angela Rudolf",
    'serial_no': "5603883",
    'map_no': "238",
    'lr_no': "234/R",
    'locality': "Nairobi",
    'objection_no': "pv876646",
    'ratable_owner': True,
    'ratable_relation': "N/A"
   }
]
```

I attempted this implementation but its not the most effective way to do so considering when data eventually grows (I tried this when I have more than 5000 records and the request takes long to return a response. I'd like to use the ORM methods to effectively populate the required queryset.

```
class ObjectUsvAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = PropertyObjection.objects.all()
    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination


    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        This view should return a list of all the properties objected.
        """

        
        qs = PropertyObjection.objects.prefetch_related('properties')


        poplulated_list = (
            {   
                "id":item.id, 
                "property": property,
                "ratable_owner": item.ratable_owner,
                "ratable_relation":  item.ratable_relation,
                "objector_name": item.objector_name

                }
            
            
            for item in qs   for property in item.properties.all()
                

        )
   

        return list(poplulated_list)
```

Comment: If there are multiple objections for a property, which objection is to be displayed?

Comment: Ah based on your existing for loop, all of them needs to be displayed. Is that correct? In this case have you had a look at `prefetch_related`? This will optimise your queries so you don't have to hit the DB for every item in your for loop. But note that `prefetch_related` will not work with `iterator` so that's another consideration.

Comment: @bdbd I want to return all objections but instead of showing the objections I show the list of properties based on the all the objections. The `iterator` will not work indeed that's why I wanted to refactor the implementation.

Comment: @bdbd I updated the queryset to `PropertyObjection.objects.prefetch_related('properties')` I've seen some minor improvements no server timeouts, but the request is taking too long (over 80 seconds) because I'm still iterating over the list to populate the queryset needed which in my opinion it's not effective

Comment: How long does it take before? And how many records are there for `PropertyObjection`?

Comment: @bdbd there more than 5000 objections is there a way I could populate the list (poplulated_list) without iterating over as done above?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue I was facing with this implementation and added a custom serializer in `serializers.py` based on the values:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    """
    This view should return a list of all the properties.
    """
    qs = PropertyObjection.objects.prefetch_related('properties').values(
        'objection_no',
        'ratable_owner',
        'ratable_relation',
        'properties__id',
        'properties__serial_no',
        'properties__map_no',
        'properties__lr_no',
        'properties__locality',
        'properties__owner',
        'properties__po_box',
        'properties__postal_code',
        'properties__address',

    ).distinct().order_by('-created_at')
    return qs
```